# Mat Paginator not working in this particular table

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab, mat-pagination

[image]

you see the data is rendered properly but the items per page is undefined plus the search input type width is shrunk but if i reload the page its proper, how come ? why this wired behavior when i visit this page and when i refresh the data is rendered properly

[image]

Code of typescript file -

.ts

```
   length;
      pageSize = 25;
      pageSizeOptions = [25, 50, 75, 100];
    
      @ViewChild('TABLE') table: ElementRef;
    
      @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
    
  ngOnInit() {
      this.adminservice.getClearedStudents();
        this.studentSub = this.adminservice.getClearedStudentsListener().subscribe(result => {
          if (result.length > 0) {
            // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-for-of
            for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
              result[i].registrationno = '[ ' + result[i].registrationno + ' ]' ;
            }
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result);
            this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
            this.length = result.length;
          }
        });
}
```

And html file code -

```
<mat-paginator [length]="length" [pageSize]="pageSize" [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

just so you know other pages with such tables the mat paginator works great only this one is troubling me, any help is appreciated, thank you in advance...

Comment: Remove [lenght] form You paginator and try again

Comment: tried still same response

Answer (score 1):

can you check if you have initialised your paginator in  ngAfterviewinit

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
```

Comment: nope no success, i tried every way, read through the angular material mat pagination docs too...

Comment: can you make a stackbliz ?

Comment: Okay i will let you know once i do that